# How to downgrade HWE?

Tags: 12.04, downgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

I was running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and was accepting all suggested upgrades. About a week ago I was prompted to upgrade the Hardware Enablement Stack because it was going out of support. So I did and I upgraded to 12.04.5. Unfortunately this upgrade brought multiple problems to my computer: if I send computer to sleep it does not recover, and if I shut it down, it restarts automatically for now apparent reason.

Now I want to undo the upgrade that I made last week. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: HWE is nothing but a new kernel. When you pick an older kernel during boot (see the options GRUB shows you) you are using the older HWE stack.

Comment: @Rinzwind, this is not true, i checked with `glmark2` benchmark (see my question [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/883807/448153)).

Comment: At least, it is no longer true with 16.04.2.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to downgrade is to remove the unsupported packages this can be done with the following command `sudo apt-get remove $(hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported)` which feeds the unsupported packages to apt for removal.

Comment: Additionally, just booting an old kernel won't have you running the older Xorg packages and may cause issues with your graphics.

Answer (score 0):

same here... what I did to revert is described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy